# authorization required when create pdf file

Tags: asp.net-web-api, pdf-generation

I am trying to generate pdf file using c# web api using the following code :

i have tried to change in the web.config but it didn't help.

```
  [HttpGet]
   public HttpResponseMessage Generate()
   {
     var stream = new MemoryStream();
  // processing the stream.

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
      {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(stream.ToArray())
      };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new 
   System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
   {
    FileName = "CertificationCard.pdf"
   };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
    new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

    return result;
}
```

I expected download pdf directly to my local disk but non worked.

Comment: Do you get an "authorization required" (401) error? Is it possible, that your controller (or the whole api) requires authorization?

Comment: no,it's not an error ,it's asking for credentials and i am using windows authentication

Comment: What happens, if you call any other Method of the Controller? Without seeing the source code of the controller and the authentication section in the web.config, it is hard to analyze this problem.